# I find "closed formula" for divisors of an positive integer, it is useful or not?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, analytic-number-theory

I find this formula, but i don't know this is worth or not.
$$d(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lim_{j\to\infty} (cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{i} \right))^{2j}$$
It is possible  to improve it to deduce formula for $P_n$ or $\pi(n)$?

Comment: I improve my question.

Answer (score 6):

No, that kind thing is not valuable -- at least it's not "valuable" in the sense that anyone is going to reward you for thinking it up.

First, it is at best debatable whether what you have there is a "closed formula". A finite summation may arguably count as "closed" in some contexts, but the limit is certainly not what people think of when they speak of "closed formulas".

(It is "closed" in the logical sense that it doesn't contain free variables other than $n$, but that is not the meaning of "closed" that is relevant here).

More to the point, the interest in having "closed formulas" for this and that is that the closed formulas are supposed to be more efficient to *calculate* and *reason about* than other more direct ways of defining the thing you're interested in. But while your formula looks like it has the right value, it is certainly *much more cumbersome* to apply than the trivial description "try all the integers from 1 up to $n$, divide $n$ by each of them, and count how many times the division comes out even". On the contrary, even evaluating your formula in the most straightforward way requires a good amount of theory for figuring out error bounds for the limit such that one knows how far to take $j$ to get an acceptable evaluation.

In principle, it there were some kind of useful symbolic manipulation one could *do* with your formula that can't be done just as straightforwardly with the trivial description (or, say, one that uses an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) or the indicator function of $\mathbb Z$ instead of that funky trigonometric limit), *then* you might be on the trace of something. But the onus would be on you to *show* what that useful manipulation would be.

Comment: @ Henning : Thank you for your complete and logical answer. but why Hardy and another mathematicians tried to find closed formula for primes number?

Comment: And formulas like this published in mathematics journals?

Comment: @Future, the key thing about trying to publish any result is that it be useful or important in some way. There are no "useful" closed formulae for prime numbers, but there are good asymptotics like the prime number theorem (which are useful as they give an accurate approximation to the number of primes less than $x$). Of course, whether a formula is useful or not is hard to say, and it's really up to the mathematical community to decide.

Answer (score 2):

It's Beautiful, but it seem's not useful. because we have no appropriate finite approximate for $\lim_{j\to\infty} (cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{i} \right))^{2j}$ in your formula.